# How to create a Cron Job in a Xamarin.Forms app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, xamarin.forms, cron

I've created a Cron Job in my API using IHostedService and the Cronos nuget package however I'm trying to do the same in my Xamarin.Forms app but it doesn't seem to work.

I've read that both Android and iOS have their own version of it with for example the Android Job Scheduler but I really want it to be an actual Cron Job and for it to work just like it does in my API.

Is there a way to do it this way ?

The tutorial I've followed is this one:
https://codeburst.io/schedule-cron-jobs-using-hostedservice-in-asp-net-core-e17c47ba06

Thank you so much.

Comment: Neither Android or iOS support the concept of "cron jobs".  There may be similar concepts in each platform.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve this directly in Xamarin.Forms
You need to use WorkManager or a background service in Xamarin.Android

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/

For iOS, you would have to follow this guide.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/

Update:

More powerful background tasks are now possible in iOS
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks

C# bindings for the classes you see on the link are available. You have to follow the above documentation. Although it might be in Swift/Objective-C, the class names and methods would be similar.

Comment: Thank you for this, however the iOS one doesn't act as a Cron Job in the sense that it talks about making the app do stuff while the app is in the background but nothing such as using the app and have it do something as the user uses it does it ?

Comment: Updated the answer with new background tasks link for iOS. Please check those.